# Sheets: Lookup formula wrong result

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have three columns. D is where I need to lookup the value in F6, and F is the column where I need to return the row.

`=lookup(D6,D11:D19,F11:F19)`
This does not return the correct row. As it should be "Never received, and is late". Instead is is returning "No Active SMC".

[image]

Answer (score 2):

`Lookup` needs the values to be sorted. As it is clearly stated in the [official documentation](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3256570?hl=en):

> The LOOKUP function will only work properly if data in search_range or
> search_result_array is sorted. Use VLOOKUP, HLOOKUP, or other related
> functions if data is not sorted.

Try [VLOOKUP](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093318?hl=en) instead:

```
=vlookup(D6,D11:F19,3,false)
```

Answer (score 0):

lookup is the wrong function. I had to use vlookup and use the index and is_sorted